# Move GuideLine in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I need to stretch the cells on the field, like in chess. Everything worked out with the field itself, but not with the cells. To scale the interface, I used a ConstraintLayout. In it, I found GuideLines that will limit the space of the cell.

I didn't understand how to move the GuideLine and how to attach elements to it.

Here is the board and cells:

[image]

I haven't tried placing lines like this yet, because I haven't figured out how to move them.

Comment: Please post the code of the layout file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Given the id of a guideline, you can move it with one of the following methods of [*ConstraintSet*](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet):

[setGuidelineBegin()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#setGuidelineBegin(int,%20int))

[setGuidelineEnd()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#setGuidelineEnd(int,%20int))

[setGuidelinePercent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#setGuidelinePercent(int,%20float))

To get the *ConstraintSet* used

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout layout;

// Get the ConstraintLayout
layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
// Get layout info for connections, etc.
set.clone(layout);
// Move guidlines here with one of the above methods working on set
// Apply changes back to the ConstraintLayout
set.applyTo(layout);
```